# Setting environment vars containing space with env

Tags: bash, environment-variables, env

I'm trying to use `env` to set environment variables (read from another source, say for example a file) for a subprocess. Essentially, I am attempting the following:

```
env VALUE=thisisatest ./somescript.sh
```

If, for example, `somescript.sh` was:

```
echo $VALUE
```

Then this would print `thisisatest` as expected. But I would like to load the variables from a file. I've gotten to this point:

```
env $(cat .vars | xargs -d '\n') ./somescript.sh
```

But, **I run into trouble when any of the variables contain spaces (and quotes don't work as expected)**. So for example:

```
env $(echo 'VALUE="this is a test"' | xargs -d '\n') ./somescript.sh
```

Will error with

```
env: is: No such file or directory
```

And trying:

```
env $(echo 'VALUE="thisisatest"' | xargs -d '\n') ./somescript.sh
```

Will give me the unexpected:

```
"thisisatest"
```

I assumed this would work properly since running `env VALUE="thisisatest" ./somescript.sh` prints it without the quotes.

From the error, I glean that for some reason env is not understanding that the quotes mean that the value that follows should be a string. However, I'm unsure how to interpolate these vars in a way that the quotes are correctly interpreted.

Can anyone provide any hints for how I could accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Also see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need double quote in command substitution, otherwise, the shell will perform field splitting with the result of command substitution:

```
$ env "$(echo 'VALUE="this is a test"')" ./somescript.sh
"this is a test"
```

For `env` reading from file, you must let the shell does field spliting, but set `IFS` to newline only, so your command won't break with space:

```
$ IFS='
'
$ env $(cat .vars) ./somescript.sh
```

If you want to read from file, it's better if you just source (aka [dot](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18)) the file in `somescript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

. .vars
: The rest of script go here
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixes the space problem. However, it breaks with multiple variables (they all get passed in as one big argument instead of separate ones). For example: `env "$(printf 'VALUE=test one\nVALUE2=test two\n' | xargs -d '\n')" printenv` prints `VALUE=test one VALUE2=test two` instead of `VALUE=test one` and `VALUE=test two` on separate lines. Is there a way to fix this or am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: I've tried wrapping each arg in quotes `env "$(printf 'VALUE=test one\nVALUE2=test two\n' | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs -d '\n')" printenv`, but this still fails.

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
env -S "`cat .vars`" command
```

First, in your file, you'll need to quote the variable value.

```
VALUE="This has spaces"
```

Then use the `-S` flag to parse the vars (which strips out the quotes).

```
env -S "`cat .vars`" command-refers-to-env-vars
```

You can't refer to `$VALUE` in the command, of course, because the command is evaluated by the shell *prior* to the action of `env`. To do that you'd need to use the following:

```
( . .vars ; echo $VALUE )
```

The parentheses open a subshell so that you don't pollute your shell with all the definitions in `.vars`. However, the variables are available only to the shell. They're not actually in the `env`, so processes wouldn't be able to access them with `process.ENV.VALUE` or `getenv("VALUE")` as with the `env -S` invocation.

You can combine both with

```
( . .vars ; env -S "`cat .vars`" command-refers-to-envs $VALUE )
```

Comment: Man, your my savior!

Comment: `env -S "$(...)"` (also `env $(...)`) didn't work for me on Mac OS X -- still split on spaces INSIDE quoted values.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's a much better way of doing this, and you can declare multiple variables without any issue.

```
env {'VALUE=thisisatest','FOO=this is a test'} printenv
```

Comment: `env VALUE='thisisatest' FOO='this is a test' printenv` seems simpler still. Even though the syntax with `{...}` seems to work, I've never seen it before, and dropping it (and the comma) makes the command as a whole look less cluttered. It is clear from the manual that `env` takes one _or more_ strings on the form `name=value`.

Comment: It's a list format. There are edge cases where env could be parsed incorrectly, especially when not invoked from the terminal but rather things such as .desktop files. As far as clutter goes, the syntax highlighting typically given to list format helps to distinguish it quite nicely in my opinion. You can also do some neat stuff where everything in a list shares the same prefix, like `--exclude=\*.{'json','js','css'}` (which excludes these particular file formats). The single quotes aren't needed in this example, mind you, but it's better for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Ah, I see now, it's actually a brace expansion! Oh, that's an odd use for it. That would obviously only work if the invoking shell knows about brace expansions. Also note that this is would be broken if there was a space after the comma in the expansion, whereas writing it "normally" would allow one to insert whitespaces between the variables for clarity (newlines, for example, if escaped).

Comment: Your experience must be different from mine because syntax highlighting makes spaces between each entry unnecessary, even a bit wasteful. Backslashing in the middle of the list to continue on a new line doesn't cause any issues, I should mention. Also, if the shell is incompatible with this syntax, it honestly probably has an even more foolproof option available to it.

Comment: Also, as far as clarity goes, it's easier to discern where the variable declaring ends and where the command begins. Very helpful if you have to declare a lot of variables at a time. Also very useful for long inclusion/exclusion argument lists with perform searches with grep.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating things.

```
$ env FOO='this is a test' printenv | egrep -i foo
FOO=this is a test
```

By the way quotes aren't part of *this* issue. Use double quotes if you want, e.g., variable substitution in your value; use single quotes if you want to prevent variable substitution, etc.

Heck, use command substitution if that suits your needs. Use formatted character strings. Use both.

```
$ env FOO=$'this\tis a test' printenv | egrep -i foo | cat -t
FOO=this^Iis a test
$ env FOO="$(echo $'this\tis a test')" printenv | egrep -i foo | cat -t
FOO=this^Iis a test
```

Oops, this may be a better example of using command substitution. The idea is to put the output of some *required command* into the variable, not just gratuitously use command substitution where none is necessary.

```
$ env FOO="$(man man)" printenv | egrep -iA5 foo=
FOO=man(1)                                    man(1)



NAME
   man - format and display the on-line manual pages
```